Question on notation of the derivative in pre-Hilbert space

Let $E$ be a real pre-Hilbert space. Show that in $E$ the mapping
$x\to\||x||$ of $E$ into $\mathbf{R}$ is differentiable at every
point $x\ne0$ and that its derivative at such a point is the linear
mapping $$s\to\frac{(s\mid x)}{||x||}.$$

I am not sure what this $(s\mid x)$ means.
However, I took the liberty to outline a proof, but since this notation with the mid-bar is unclear, I am not sure I  am not the right track? Any suggestions welcome.
Thanks
Attempt:
We need to show first that there exists a linear mapping $u:x\to||x||$ of $E$ onto $\mathbf{R}$, and that this mapping is differentiable at every point. To be differentiable at every point, it must be continuous and the derivative must exists.
In order to prove this, we need to show that there exists a function that is tangent at $x_0$ to a function $f$.  There is at most one mapping of the form $$x\to f(x_0)+u(x-x_0)$$ where $u$ is linear.
Consider two such functions $$x\to f(x_0)+u_1(x-x_0)$$ and $$x\to f(x_0)+u_2(x-x_0)$$ which are tangent at $x_0$, then the linear mapping of the two functions is $$v=u_1-u_2,$$ that means there exists a limit such that $$\lim_{y\to0,y\ne0}\frac{||{v(y)}||}{||{y}||}=0$$
However, from this form to the notation $$s\to\frac{(s\mid x)}{||x||},$$ something is missing.
There is not a clear relation between the given limit  and $s\to\frac{(s\mid x)}{||x||}$. If we put $$y=\frac{rx}{||x||}$$, then we obtain
$$\lim_{y\to0,y\ne0}\frac{||{v(\frac{rx}{||x||})}||}{||{\frac{rx}{||x||}}||}=0$$
but this is still not the same as$$s\to\frac{(s\mid x)}{||x||}.$$ According to Dieudonne, we should use the formula
$$(s,t)\to[x\cdot t]+ [s\cdot y],$$
but how can this be applied to this case?
Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

$(s\mid x)$ is the inner product of $s$ and $x$.

@superunknown The dot notation is rarely used to denote the inner product except when working with row/column vectors. In general Hilbert spaces, $\langle x,y\rangle$ is fairly common. The notation $(x|y)$ is also used, but somewhat less commonly. Physicists use bra-ket notation, which takes the form $\langle x|y\rangle$.

@superunknown I can't think of any instances wherein $\sqrt{ s\cdot x}$ (or $\sqrt{(x|y)}$) would appear, because the inner product of $s$ with $x$ need not be a real number, and even if it is, it need not be non-negative. Perhaps you're thinking of the norm, which is $|x|=\sqrt{(x|x)}$.

Here's a hint: If $U$ is an open subset of a Hilbert space and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly positive, differentiable function on $U$, then $$(f^2)'=2ff'.$$ So if we can calculate $(f^2)'$, we can solve for $f'$.

Yes. So if we take $U={x:|x|\neq 0}$ and $f(x)=|x|$, then $f^2=|x|^2=( x|x)$. This expression relates the norm to the inner product. Can you calculate $(f^2)'$?

What you've written here doesn't have $f'$ in it anywhere.

You have both $|x|$ and $|x|$. What is the difference?

What does that mean, and where did it come from? $f'$ is what you're supposed to be calculating, so if you already knew $f'$, you would be done already.

What does the notation $|x|$ mean?

$x$ is a vector in a pre-Hilbert space. "$x$ is always positive" doesn't mean anything in this context.

No. $s$ is not the name of the function. The notation $s\mapsto \frac{(s|x)}{|x|}$ means that $s$ is the argument (input) into the function, not the function itself.

The standard goes by
In an orthonormal basis in a real pre Hilbert space, the scalar products is
$$\left|\  x,\ y \ \right|_2 = \left| \ x^T \ y \ \right|_1  = \sum x_i y_i$$.
$$\left|x \right|_2 = \left< x, x\right>_2 = | x^T x |_1 = \sum x_i^2$$
$$\text{||}x\text{||} = \sqrt{\sum x_i^2}$$
By the general d-machine (linearity, product and chain rules) one has the 1-form, whose coefficients of $ \mathbf dx_k$ form the gradient vector
$$ \mathbf d \ \text{||}x\text{||} = \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \partial_{x_k} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1 }^n x_i^2} \right)  \  \mathbf d x_k = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(  \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\sum_{i=1 }^n x_i^2}} \sum_{i=1 }^n\left(2 \delta_{ik} x_i\right)\right)  \   \mathbf d x_k =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k }{\text{||}x\text{||}} \ \mathbf d x_k $$
The vector $$\frac{x_k}{\text{||}x\text{||}}$$ is a unit vector, it may be called the radial unit vector at any point $x$ or its projection to the unit sphere.  So the 1-form of the 2-norm in euclidean $\mathbb R^n$  is producing the orthonormal bundle to the  unit sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1}$
